# How to use platform architecture in Maven to determine dependency?

Tags: maven, cross-platform

As the question states is there a nice way to use dependencies based on the platform architecture while building maven artefacts. I know about profiles and how to use them. For this special purpose i dont want to incorporate them into my build.

*The problem in detail could be described as follows:*

- Multi module maven project
- Continous integration and people on the project use evenly distributed platform architectures
- Dependency to native system library

*Solutions which i do not want to use in the settings:*

- No dependency redundancy
- **No maven profiles** (or at least maven profiles which are automatically chosen by platform architecture)

*As an example*:

**Person1**

- (using linux i686) builds project
- x86 libaries are bundled to every subproject and the resulting artefacts are being build

**Person2**

- (using win32) builds project
- 32 bit librariers are bundled as above

**Continous integration**

- is running like the production environment on linux amd64
- integrate amd64 libraries

**Edit about Profiles**

I know that profiles are one solution to do this. But what i want to achieve is that you checkout your project from some random source version control and build a project with native libraries out of the box without doing anything (as long as the platform meets the requirement of the configured ones).

I do not want to configure these profile settings nor i want to run a specific target explicitally. If there is such thing with profiles i would like to see an example which determines automatically the platform architecture and runs a target. IF there is one without profiles i would prefer it because it is much less complex while having different existent combinations of profiles(including tests and other usecases).

Having solely profiles feels a little bloated to me and manual efforts are required.

I hope someone has a neat suggestion because im somehow stuck on this.

Comment: I struggle with this idea: Maven has decided how you do things. Profiles is how you do this. Therefore, you must use profiles to do this. Maven isn't flexible - it's constrained. That is its strength.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I don't know of any way to do this without profiles.  This is the main use case for which profiles were added to maven.  You can do it using the following:

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <activation>
      <os>
        <name>Windows XP</name>
        <family>Windows</family>
        <arch>x86</arch>
      </os>
    </activation>
    ...
  </profile>
  <profile>
    <activation>
      <os>
        <family>Linux</family>
        <arch>x64</arch>
      </os>
    </activation>
    ...
  </profile>
  <profile>
    <activation>
      <property>
         <name>integration-test</name>
      </property>
    </activation>
    ...
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

Then, when someone checks out a project and builds it on a Linux x64 machine, they will automatically get everything under the Linux x64 profile.  If they also provided the property `-Dintegration-test` on the command line, they would activate the integration-test profile as well.  You can have any number of active profiles, which are combined to create the effective POM for the build.  These profiles can be defined in a shared parent POM for all projects that you work on, so developers don't have to change their settings.xml files.

To get more info on the activation of profiles, check out: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html.

Comment: `<family>Linux</family><arch>x64</arch>` did not work in my case (8u25 on 64-bit Linux 3.16.0). `<family>Linux</family><arch>amd64</arch>` did. Not sure how to match a little more generically.

Comment: And on Red Hat it will probably be `x86_64`.

Answer (score 1):

What is the problem with using profiles? They have been made exactly for such a situation. You can specify the profile action by OS/platform and add the dependency. Completely transparent.

The other way would be to move your core lib to a separate module and have a module for each platform.

Comment: Im using currently profiles to sub group test sets. If I invent a different logical group of subsets i need to configure each combination of them therefore i do not want to have this. The corelib is a manual way i wanted to know how this could be done automatically.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding profiles.  You can have your test set profiles and then have another set of profiles that change the dependencies.  The `<activation>` group on the profile determines when it is used, and multiple profiles can be active at once.

Comment: I second Ryan's answer. But be careful, too many profiles make build unpredictable and unmanageable. You should maybe consider test modules rather than test profiles.

Comment: @Ryan thats aboslutely true. I know about multiple profiles and also about activation of multiple profiles at once but that doesnt change the complexity introduced by various combinations. And it doesnt solve my automation problem sadly. I edit my post to make it more clear.